# Azure YAML lowering a variable from parameters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an `azure-pipelines.yml` file which manage the deployment of one of my service.
The logic of the deployment is in another repository. Here is a simplified version of the file :

```
variables:
  serviceName: $(System.TeamProject)

stages:
- template: standard-services-pipeline.yml@templates
  parameters:
    serviceName: ${{ variables.serviceName }}
```

During the process, another yml file needs my `ServiceName`, but lowered. Here is the simplified version :

```
parameters:
- name: serviceName
  type: string

variables:
- name: lowerName
  value: ${{ lower(parameters.serviceName) }}

steps:
- script: echo $(lowerName)
```

But this does not work. I tried a few things, like `- script: echo ${{ lower(parameters.serviceName) }}`, or even `- script: echo ${{ '$(lower((parameters.serviceName))' }}`
But none of my tries succedeed.

How can I store a lowered version of my runtime `serviceName` variable in my `lowerName` variable please ?

**UPDATE :**

Here are some more detailed tries I made.

The `serviceName` variable is defined in the `azure-pipelines.yml` of the service's repository. This file calls the `standard-services-pipeline.yml` of another repository. It passes the `serviceName` through the parameters as shown in my first code bloc.

All of the following attempts are modifications and tests made inside the `standard-services-pipeline.yml`. I simplified this file everytime to make it more readable and deleted the unecessary parts.

Attempt 1

```
parameters:

- name: serviceName
  type: string

variables:
- name: lowerName
  value: ${{ lower(parameters.serviceName) }}

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.serviceName }} 
 # Script contents :
 # echo IdentityProvider (name of the service, CamelCase)
 # Result :
 # IdentityProvider
- script: echo ${{ lower(parameters.serviceName) }}
 # Script contents :
 # echo IdentityProvider
 # Result :
 # IdentityProvider
- script: echo ${{ variables.lowerName }}
 # Script contents :
 # echo IdentityProvider
 # Result :
 # IdentityProvider
```

Attempt 2

```
parameters:
- name: serviceName
  type: string

variables:
- name: lowerName
  value: ${{ lower(parameters.serviceName) }}

steps:
- script: echo $(variables.lowerName)
 # Script contents :
 # echo IdentityProvider
 # Result :
 # IdentityProvider
```

Attempt 3

```
parameters:
- name: serviceName
  type: string

variables:
- name: lowerName
  value: ${{ lower(parameters.serviceName) }}

steps:
- script: echo $(lowerName)
 # Script contents :
 # echo IdentityProvider
 # Result :
 # IdentityProvider
```

Attempt 4

```
parameters:
- name: serviceName
  type: string

variables:
- name: lowerName
  value: ${{ lower(parameters.serviceName) }}

steps:
- script: echo ${{ lower('$(parameters.serviceName)') }}
 # Script contents :
 # echo $(parameters.servicename)
 # Result :
 #
```

Attempt 5

```
parameters:
- name: serviceName
  type: string

variables:
- name: lowerName
  value: ${{ lower(parameters.serviceName) }}

steps:
- script: ${{format('{0} {1}', 'echo', '$(lower(parameters.serviceName))')}}
 # Script contents :
 # echo $(lower(parameters.serviceName))
 # Result :
 # command substitution: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `parameters.serviceName'
 # command substitution: line 2: `lower(parameters.serviceName))'
```

Comment: Where are you defining the variable `serviceName` in the first place? What does "none of my tries succeeded" mean? You need to explain what **happened**, not just that it didn't work.

Comment: The `serviceName` is defined in the `azure-pipelines.yml`. This variable is passed to my second yml file from other repository as it's shown at the beginning of my post.

Sorry if I skipped the detailed tries, retrieving the commits corresponding to the failed pipelines was painful because my scripts are on differents repositories and I didn't think that posting my failed tries would help in anything else than showing that I actually tried something before coming here.

Anyway, I updated the question with the most pertinents tries, the others are usually in error because of a typo.

Comment: You added a ton of additional information without providing the information I specifically requested: Where are you setting a value for the `serviceName` variable? There is *some* place where that variable is being defined, not being passed in from another source. I want to see **where that value is initially defined**.

Comment: As I already stated, the variable is defined at the beginning of the first file : `serviceName: $(System.TeamProject)`. The `System.TeamProject` is a predefined variable populated by Azure. You can learn more about it here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services

Comment: In your question, can you clarify precisely what went *wrong* in your various attempts? Compile-time errors, run-time errors, missing output, incorrect output, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this in this way:

Main pipeline

```yaml
variables:
  serviceName: $(System.TeamProject)

stages:
- template: template.yaml
  parameters:
    serviceName: ${{ variables.serviceName }}
```

Template

```
parameters:
- name: serviceName
  type: string

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: |
        name="${{ parameters.serviceName }}"
        lowercase_name=$(echo "$name" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=lowerName;]'$lowercase_name'"

    - script: echo $(lowerName)
```

I passed service name as parameter and then lower it in bash and used logging command to create variable.

[image]

You can also check this [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/lower-expression-is-affecting-the-name-of-the-vari/1100720)